# gRPC Client -->ALB--->Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, grpc

I have gRPC Client with Python code as below and making a gRPC call though ALB but seeing ssl handshake errors.I have root cert in place in client certs directory but still handshake is failing.

Client gRPC Python Code :

import grpc
import helloworld_pb2
import helloworld_pb2_grpc

def run():
# NOTE(gRPC Python Team): .close() is possible on a channel and should be
# used in circumstances in which the with statement does not fit the needs
# of the code.
print("Will try to greet world ...")
creds = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(root_certificates=None, private_key=None, certificate_chain=None)
with grpc.secure_channel('alb_dns_name:443', creds) as channel:
stub = helloworld_pb2_grpc.GreeterStub(channel)
response = stub.SayHello(helloworld_pb2.HelloRequest(name="you"))
print("Greeter client received: " + response.message)

if **name** == "**main**":
logging.basicConfig()
run()

Flow is like this , ALB have https/443 listener with gRPC target Group

Client----->ALB----->Grpc Server

I am seeing following error when making call :

E1230 20:45:56.633317836    3420 ssl_transport_security.cc:1511]       Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED.
E1230 20:45:56.637107019    3420 ssl_transport_security.cc:1511]       Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ec2-user/grpc/examples/python/helloworld/grpc/examples/python/helloworld/greeter_client.py", line 39, in 
run()
File "/home/ec2-user/grpc/examples/python/helloworld/grpc/examples/python/helloworld/greeter_client.py", line 33, in run
response = stub.SayHello(helloworld_pb2.HelloRequest(name="you"))
File "/home/ec2-user/grpc/examples/python/helloworld/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 1160, in **call**
return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
File "/home/ec2-user/grpc/examples/python/helloworld/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 1003, in _end_unary_response_blocking
raise _InactiveRpcError(state)  # pytype: disable=not-instantiable
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
details = "failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:13.55.220.127:443: Ssl handshake failed: SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED"
debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer  {created_time:"2023-12-30T20:45:56.637312405+00:00", grpc_status:14, grpc_message:"failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:13.55.220.127:443: Ssl handshake failed: SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED"}"

Openssl is working fine and curl also working fine and i am getting 464 status code but the gRPC is failing with SSL fail code.

Any ideas on this

Comment: Your question is near unreadable. Please indent all code / log lines with 4 spaces to try to make it more readable. If your client can't validate the AWS certificate I would check if it has the AWS root cert in its certificate store.